# Google SERP links going to random affiliate shopping sites

Tags: firefox, malware, google-search, spyware, adware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Very odd issue here. I'm normally quite 'in the know' when it comes to dealing with adware/spyware/malware etc but this one has me stumped.

On the odd google serch, when I click a link in the results, instead of taking me to the site I have suggested, I get taken to a random shopping site with an obvious affiliate link for that site.

Running Firefox (latest)
Addons:
YSLow
Firebug
Google Page Speed
Awesome Screenshot
Alexa Toolbar
IE tab 2
Translate This!
View Cookies
Web Developer

I have ran AVG scan, malwarebytes and spybot S&D and nothing odd comes up apart from some cookies.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's malware. Dig deeper.

Comment: @dnbrv any suggestions on what else to run?

Comment: Have you tried the [canonical answer](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) on the subject?